# How to Add Hyperlinks to Google Forms user Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to add hyperlinked rows to a `GridItem`, ideally that act as tooltips. Am I trying to do more than is possible with Google Apps Script?

Here's the situation: I have a `GridItem` type question that has lengthy row descriptions. To clean up the interface, I'd like to present a short summary of the description that, when clicked/hovered, reveals the full text. To do this, I'd need to turn the short summary into a hyperlink. However, I haven't seen any way to insert hyperlinks in `GridItem` rows. I thought that Google Apps Script may allow me to do this.

So far, I've tried entering a string followed by `.setLinkUrl()`, using `createAnchor('text', url)`, using markdown, and actually inserting, as text, `<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>'` for the row. Nothing has worked so far.

Is this possible at all?

EDIT:
I apologize - I didn't research this question well enough before posting. Turns out Google Forms auto-detects URLs and posts them as links in the live form. I still have an issue with this, though - I'd rather have some specified text displayed to the user instead of the URL (some of my URLs are lengthy). Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: For shortening the URL, you can use URL shortener:  https://goo.gl/

Answer (score -1):

You can design the main elements of the Google form the normal way. Then preview the live form, copy the generated html file, hosted in your website.
Then you can replace the `<a>...</a>` tag that is generated by Google Form by one you need e.g. `<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>`

- keep sure you don't disturb any styles or code that may be needed by the Google form to work.
- This solution need to have your own web hosting.
- You will need to point your users to your website not the live form preview.